# Laravel Eloquent - Saving, Updating and Deleting request into related tables

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to develop an API of some sort with Laravel 5.4 and have been trying to save,update and delete sales with its related sales details but still not making any head way after trying and going through a lot of code samples found here.
I want to be able to:

1. Save sales and its sales details (without mapping the fields one by one)
2. Update a sale and its sales details (without mapping the fields one by one)
3. Delete  a sale and its details all at once.

below are my codes

**Sale Model Relationship**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\SalesDetail;

class Sale extends Model
{
//
  protected $fillable=[
    'receipt',
    'customer',
    'total_cost',
    'amount_paid',
    'payment_type',
    'discount_percent',
    'discount_amount'

  ];

  // a sale has many sales details
  public function saleDetails(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SalesDetail');
  }
}
```

**Sales Detail Model Relationship**

```
 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Models\Sale;

 class SalesDetail extends Model
 {
  //
  protected $fillable=[
    // 'sales_id',
    'category',
    'menu',
    'unit',
    'quantity',
    'cost'

   ];

   // A sales detail  belongs to a sale
   public function sale(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sale');
   }
 }
```

**Sales Controller - Save Function (Updated - Works fine Now)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //Validate request data
     $this->validate($request,['receipt'=>'required']);

     //Save sales without sales details data
    $sale = Sale::create($request->except(['sale_details']));

    //Get sales details data
    $saledetails = $request->sale_details;

    //Loop through sales details
    foreach ($saledetails as $data){

        //Create a new instance of sales details model
        $details = new SalesDetail;

        //fill the model properties (mass assignment) with the data
        $details->fill($data);

        //Save and link sales details to sales 
        $sale->saleDetails()->save($details);

    }

    return 'Sale saved successfully';
}
```

**Sales Controller - Update Function**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
      $this->validate($request,['receipt'=>'required']);

    $sale = Sale::with('saleDetails')->findOrFail($id);

    $input=$request->all();
    $sale->fill($input)->save();

    return 'Sale updated successfully';
}
```

**Sales Controller - Delete Function**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
    Sale::with('saleDetails')->whereId($id)->first()->delete();

    return 'Sale deleted sucessfully';
}
```

**Sample Sales Data**

```
{
"id": 1,
"receipt": "RT124558",
"customer": "John Dumelo",
"total_cost": 1000,
"amount_paid": 900,
"payment_type": "Cash",
"discount_percent": 0.1,
"discount_amount": 100,
"created_at": "2017-06-12 00:00:00",
"updated_at": "2017-06-12 00:00:00",
"sale_details": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sale_id": 1,
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Eater",
        "unit": "Large",
        "quantity": 10,
        "cost": 50,
        "created_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sale_id": 1,
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Deluze",
        "unit": "Medium",
        "quantity": 5,
        "cost": 30,
        "created_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am a novice in Laravel and wish i could get help on this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set the protected $fillable or $guarded properties on your Models? That will prevent mass assignment if not properly mapped out.

Comment: Yes please i have thats also set on the two models for mass assignment

Comment: post your models with those properties please.

Comment: post update please

Comment: Check to be sure you aren't including the _token or _method hidden fields when you're attempting to save a model. In the sales save method: $sale = Sale::create($request->except(['sale_details'])); might have more input data in there than you realize.

Comment: They are not included please, actually; 
$sale = Sale::create($request->except(['sale_details'])); - works fine and saves the sales data but the sales details data do not get saved at all in its related table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sales Controller - Save Function (Updated - Works fine Now)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //Validate request data
     $this->validate($request,['receipt'=>'required']);

     //Save sales without sales details data
    $sale = Sale::create($request->except(['sale_details']));

    //Get sales details data
    $saledetails = $request->sale_details;

    //Loop through sales details
    foreach ($saledetails as $data){

        //Create a new instance of sales details model
        $details = new SalesDetail;

        //fill the model properties (mass assignment) with the data
        $details->fill($data);

        //Save and link sales details to sales 
        $sale->saleDetails()->save($details);

    }

    return 'Sale saved successfully';
}
```

**Sales Controller - Update Function (Updated - Works fine Now)**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
      $this->validate($request,['receipt'=>'required']);

    $sale=Sale::findOrFail($id);
   $saleinput = $request->except(['sale_details']);

    $sale->fill($saleinput)->save();

    $saledetails = $request->sale_details;

    //Delete previous sales details
    SalesDetail::where('sale_id', $id)->delete();

    foreach ($saledetails as $data){
        $details = new SalesDetail;
        $details->fill($data);
        $sale->saleDetails()->save($details);

    }

    return 'Sale updated successfully';
}
```

**Sales Controller - Delete Function (Updated - Works fine Now)**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //Delete sales details before deleting sales
    SalesDetail::where('sale_id', $id)->delete();
    Sale::whereId($id)->first()->delete();


    return 'Sale deleted sucessfully';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the Sale and SaleDetail models independently, then associating them after by:

```
$sale->saleDetails()->associate($details);
```

according to your SaleDetails model, you need to filter this down:

```
"sale_details": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sale_id": 1,
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Eater",
        "unit": "Large",
        "quantity": 10,
        "cost": 50,
        "created_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sale_id": 1,
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Deluze",
        "unit": "Medium",
        "quantity": 5,
        "cost": 30,
        "created_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-14 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
```

to only inlclude this:

```
"sale_details": [
    {
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Eater",
        "unit": "Large",
        "quantity": 10,
        "cost": 50
    },
    {
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Deluze",
        "unit": "Medium",
        "quantity": 5,
        "cost": 30
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Using this - $details = SalesDetail::create($request->only(['sale_details'])); to save the Sales Details does not work.

Also trying to loop through and saving also does not work like;

$m_details = $request->sale_details;
        foreach ($m_details as $detail){
            $details = SalesDetail::create($detail);
            // return $details;
        }

Comment: I have a feeling your SaleDetail is failing to save because your're including the id, created_at and updated_at fields. but your model only allows for category, menu, unit, quantity and cost.

Comment: No please,
i am sending this data through the request: -

{
    "receipt": "RT555",
    "customer": "John Dumelo",
    "total_cost": 1000,
    "amount_paid": 900,
    "payment_type": "Cash",
    "discount_percent": 0.1,
    "discount_amount": 100,
    "sale_details": [
      {
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Eater",
        "unit": "Large",
        "quantity": 10,
        "cost": 50
      },
      {
        "category": "Pizza",
        "menu": "Meat Lover",
        "unit": "Large",
        "quantity": 10,
        "cost": 50
      }
      ]
}

Comment: Yes please , i have filtered it down but still not saving

Comment: Try a simple test by saving just one SaleDetails model and don't use create() or fill(), explicity set each property and then call save() on the model.

Comment: I just did that but it also seems not to work. kindly find above the updated code for the save function. hope i am not doing something wrong there.

Comment: What is the error or exception you're getting say? Do you have log files?

Comment: Using Postman to pass the data and its given me "Status: 500 Internal Server Error". And no i dont have log files please

Comment: I have been able to work on the Save function now, and it works fine, I am now left with the *Update" and "Delete" functions which i need help with.